# ChangePassword() method not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
SQLiteConnection connString = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
using (var command = connString.CreateCommand())
{           
     try
     {
          connString.SetPassword(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password1"]);

          connString.Open();
          connString.ChangePassword((String)null);
          connString.ChangePassword(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password2"]);
          connString.Close();
          connString.Dispose();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          Console.Write(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
     }
}
```

I'm trying to test SQLite by having a simple console application. I'm using an app.config file to read passwords and connection string  from. The code is able to set the password the very first time it runs but if I open the connection and try to change password by calling ChangePassWord() method,  the password is not changed. I also try to set password to null and then reset it to some new password, but that doesn't work either.

The error is 
*File Opened that is not a database file. File is encrypted or is not a database*

Some other people have the same problem: [ChangePassword method problem](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/3075/10789.aspx#10789).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure. But for some reason reading the connection string from the app.config could have some bearing on it. I took out the connection string and decided to hardcode it like so

```
SQLiteConnection connString = new SQLiteConnection("data source=\".\\SomeDatabase\"");
```

before was like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection"
        connectionString="data source=&quot;.\SomeDatabase&quot;"
        providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope this helps somebody